# How to fix the Validation Error from HTTP Post method

Tags: asp.net-core, http-post, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created a project using default web api template code for asp.net core 5
`<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>`
Then I added a method to test a post request in the WeatherForecastController

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult<string> PostMethod([FromBody]string jsonString)
 {            
     return Ok(jsonString);
 }
```

If I remove the[FromBody] the code works fine. If I add [FromBody] and type something in the body like asdfasdf from swagger, it fails with 400 status error

> {
> "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
> "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
> "status": 400,
> "traceId": "00-78bd11a5cea5244998ade80c059479d0-8cb569e070ca0047-00",
> "errors": {
> "$": [
> "'a' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0."
> ]
> }
> }

Not able to figure out what the issue is! Could someone explain what causes this and would be great if you can point me to some resource that helps me understand how this validation is done. There was no data annotations done here with this simple code.

Body in Swagger!! :)
[image]

Thanks in advance
Murthy

Comment: Hi @Murthy,what is your body in your swagger? can you share it?

Comment: @Yinqiu, Edited the post to add the image for body in swagger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your body is not a string type,please add `""`,change it to

```
"xxxxx"
```

Test Result:
[image]

Comment: :) Really This was it! Thanks for the solution :) :)

Comment: Glad can help you :)